# How to check whether a user uses a VPN connection on a my server?

Tags: linux, vpn

I am administrating 10 servers and it seems like someone among the users is using VPN. I do not have root credentials but I can impose a control over the traffic. I want to check whether any of my users is using a VPN. Do you have any idea of how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way for you to determine if your users are using a VPN.

The real question is: why do you care?